# Scraping housing dataset row by row from Estate Agent's website

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, pandas, selenium

I have written web scraping code with selenium with python3 for a dynamic site (it was my first project that is why I started with selenium). In my code I extracted the values and created DataFrame.

My question is, while extracting the values I created lists like this
and when the for loop ends. So I wanted to ask you if there is more efficient way to write (Created the necessary variables) without lists and then appending values to the different data structure?

To be more precise, I was wondering if it is okay to write like at the below :

```py
* name, m_2_gross, m_2_net, age_of_building, floor_number = [], [], [], [], []
```

and then appending each of them line by line. Is it okay to write this way? While I was looking at the Stack Overflow forums a lot of people recommended other people to generate the lists with for loops or to create by using default dictionaries.

```
import time
from random import randint
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


# Created a sleep function to randomize sleep command
def random_time(short_time, long_time):
    rand_sleep_time = randint(short_time, long_time)
    return time.sleep(rand_sleep_time) 


# Gets the house list and checks if the ad pops up to house list and if it does, then discard it from the list 
def pop_up_remover(browser):
    check_list = WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, "searchResultsItem")))
    check_list.pop(3)
    try:
        house_pop_up = browser.find_element(
            by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="searchResultsPromoSuper")
        if house_pop_up in check_list:
            check_list.remove(house_pop_up)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    return check_list


def main():
    # Browser object has been created by merging Selenium Webdriver and Service.
    s = Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)

    # Browser object got the internet site.Then the pop ups have been closed.
    browser.get("https://www.sahibinden.com/en/for-sale-flat/izmir-karsiyaka-nergiz-demirkopru-mh.")
    browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div[12]").click()
    browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']").click()

    # Created the necessary variables
    name, m_2_gross, m_2_net, age_of_building, floor_number = [], [], [], [], []
    number_of_bathrooms, number_of_rooms, heating, seller, price = [], [], [], [], []

    # Site Dependent values have been created
    total_ad_number = int((browser.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="result-text").text).split()[0])
    house_num_per_page = int(browser.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="Limit20").text)
    total_page = (total_ad_number // house_num_per_page) + 1


    # The Loop starts
    for _ in range(total_page):
        house_list = pop_up_remover(browser)
        random_time(2, 4)
            
        for house_number in range(len(house_list)):
            house_list = pop_up_remover(browser)   
            house_list[house_number].click()

            ad_name = browser.find_element(
                by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='classifiedDetail']/div/div[1]/h1")
            ad_m_2_gross = browser.find_element(
                by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='classifiedDetail']/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[5]/span")
            ad_m_2_net = browser.find_element(
                by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='classifiedDetail']/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[6]/span")
            ad_age_of_building = browser.find_element(
                by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='classifiedDetail']/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[8]/span")
            ad_floor_number = browser.find_element(
                by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='classifiedDetail']/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[9]/span")
            ad_number_of_bathrooms = browser.find_element(
                by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='classifiedDetail']/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[12]/span")
            ad_number_of_rooms = browser.find_element(
                by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='classifiedDetail']/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[7]/span")
            ad_heating = browser.find_element(
                by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='classifiedDetail']/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[11]/span")
            ad_price = browser.find_element(
                by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id='classifiedDetail']/div/div[2]/div[2]/h3")

            for element in ["user-info-store-name", "storeInfo", "username-info-area"]:   
                try:
                    ad_seller = browser.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=element)
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    pass
            
            # The values that are extracted appended to the main list 
            name.append(ad_name.text)
            m_2_gross.append(ad_m_2_gross.text)
            m_2_net.append(ad_m_2_net.text)
            age_of_building.append(ad_age_of_building.text)
            floor_number.append(ad_floor_number.text)
            number_of_bathrooms.append(ad_number_of_bathrooms.text)
            number_of_rooms.append(ad_number_of_rooms.text)
            heating.append(ad_heating.text)
            seller.append(ad_seller.text)
            price.append(ad_price.text)



            # Goes back to previous browser
            browser.execute_script('window.history.go(-1)')

            random_time(2,3)
            # Checks whether there is a "next" button.
            if (house_number + 1)==len(house_list) :
                buttons = browser.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="prevNextBut")
                if (len(buttons)==1 and len(house_list)==house_num_per_page):
                    # If it has 1 button and is equal to 20 then it is at the first page.
                    buttons[0].click()
                elif len(buttons) == 2:
                    buttons[1].click()
                else:
                    print("Search is finished")
                    
            random_time(4,6)        
                
    browser.quit()

    # Writing the values as DataFrames
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {"name": name,
        "m_2_gross": m_2_gross,
        "m_2_net": m_2_net,
        "age_of_building":age_of_building,
        "floor_number":floor_number,
        "number_of_bathrooms":number_of_bathrooms,
        "number_of_rooms":number_of_rooms,
        "heating":heating,
        "seller":seller,
        "price":price})

    df.to_excel("Demirköprü.xlsx", sheet_name="1")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks for the notification. @Reinderien

Comment: When I access the website, it says _You are trying to access from outside of Turkey._, and requires authentication. You are not doing authentication here. Is that because in your region none is needed?

Comment: Actually i am from Turkey so that is why i did not have to do it. I will check the code out and will try to deal with authentication and update the code. thank you for the feed back @Reinderien